# Проблема с получением элементов массива в другом массиве JSON документа

Tags: json, delphi

Есть JSON документ примерно такого содержания:

```
{
"ORGANIZATION_1":   {
    "Name":"TEST1",
    "okp":[
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"]
        ],
    "skp":[
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"],
        ["12345","12345","12345"]
        ],
    }
}
```

Достаю элементы вот так:

```
...
uses System.JSON;
....
procedure Get_Data(s: string);
var
    Json: TJSONObject;
    JS : TJSONObject;
    JSAr, JSAr2 : TJSONArray;
    i,k: integer;
    valume1, valume2, valume3 : string;
begin

    Json := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(S) as TJSONObject;
    if Assigned(Json) then
        begin
            JS      := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(Json.GetValue('ORGANIZATION_1').ToString) as TJSONObject;
            JSAr    := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JS.GetValue('okp').ToString) as TJSONArray;

             if JSAr.Size <> 0 then
                begin
                    for k := 0 to JSAr.Size-1 do                    //проходимся по всем 15 значениям массива
                        begin
                            JSAr2:= JSAr.Items[k] as TJSONArray;

                            valume1   := JSAr2.Items[0].ToString;
                            valume2   := JSAr2.Items[1].ToString;
                            valume3   := JSAr2.Items[2].ToString;

                        end;
                end;
        end;
end;
```

Проблема заключается в следующем: 
Если переменные **valume1, valume2, valume3** - строки, то проблем нет. Данные получаю. Но при попытке конвертировать их в тип Extended (там могут быть дробные числа), функцией StrToFloat - ничего не происходит. Программа останавливается и даже ошибок не выдает. Но и в переменные ничего не заносится. Подскажите, что делаю не так? Как правильно получать данные из такой структуры JSON документа? Большое спасибо!

Comment: С дробными числами, обычно разделитель дробной части шалит (точка или запятая). Делайте `StringReplace` или шаманства с локалями.

Comment: @Kromster, ТОЧНО!!! Как я мог забыть об этом! ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 1):

У функции StrToFloat есть перегруженная версия с двумя аргументами

```
function StrToFloat(const S: string; const AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings): Extended;
```

Я при работе с JSON, как правило, объявляю глобальную переменную

```
JsonFS: TFormatSettings;
```

и инициализирую ее нужными настройками, в частности

```
JsonFS.DecimalSeparator := '.';
```

и далее использую как второй аргумент StrToFloat

Comment: Большое спасибо, за ответ! надо будет взять на заметку!))